# Error 404: web-animations-next/animations.html not found

Tags: polymer, material-design, web-component

I am trying to include the paper-dropdown menu in my page but I get the above error. I use git clone (polymer-element-repo) to add whatever components I want to use or whichever components are missing but the (web-animations-next) repo does not exist. below is a screen capture of the error from the browser window and below that, a list of all the components I currently have. Can someone please help me get past this error [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Install the polymer elements using bower or pull the repo again.

```
bower install Polymer/polymer
```

Installing using bower is the recommended method of installing polymer elements.

Refer : [Getting the Code](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/getting-the-code.html)

Comment: I know bower is the recommended way, but whenever I run bower I get this error message:

TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'toLowerCase'
    at Function.Buffer.isEncoding (buffer.js:240:32)
    at assertEncoding (evalmachine.<anonymous>:98:27)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (evalmachine.<anonymous>:908:3)
    at Object.create.all.set (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/configstore.js:63:8)
    at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/configstore.js:26:11)
    at new Insi..........

Comment: maybe try chrome dev editor. make a local version of your app everything but the bower folder then let CDE do the bower download and copy the bower_components folder to your server. so far i have had decent luck with letting cde be the package management.

Comment: I'm encountering the exact same issue as the OP, and I installed via the recommended method, using bower.

Comment: ok found that my issue was related to a bug that was patched 16 days ago (https://github.com/Polymer/core-animation/pull/15). Unfortunately `bower update` doesn't work. I may need some manual patching for now.